# Formal notation for function equality

Tags: notation

Is there a short-hand notation for
$$
f(x) = 1 \quad \forall x
$$
?

I've seen $f\equiv 1$ being used before, but found some some might (mis)interpret that as $f:=1$ (in the sense of definition), i.e., $f$ being the number $1$.

Comment: I tend to interpret $\equiv$ in the way you want. Also, I usually don't take $:=$ to mean a definition, so much as an instance. E.g. $f:=1$ to me means that $f$ will represent $1,$ but it is not a definition of $f.$

Comment: I also interpret $\equiv$ in the way you want. (I do take $:=$ to denote a definition.)

Comment: $A\triangleq B$ is sometimes okay, and $\newcommand\assign{\mathinner{:=}}A\assign B$ sometimes represent $A\gets B$ in context of computer programmng.

Comment: That's why the (sub)section *notation* is always a great idea at the beginning of any book or paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and use $\equiv$. To prevent any possibility of misunderstanding, you can use the word "constant" the first time this notation appears. As in "let $f$ be the constant function $f\equiv1$..."